# Cross referencing line numbers between multiple documents with the pagewise option set

Tags: cross-referencing, line-numbering, xr, lineno

I am using the lineno package with pagewise numberings set. I would like to reference these line numbers from another file, so I am using the xr package. However, it doesn't seem to pick up on the pagewise aspect and gives the references as if it were continuous.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\newcommand{\R}[1]{\linelabel{#1}}
\newcommand{\lr}[1]{page~\pageref{#1}, line~\lineref{#1}}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
1 st page

an extra line

and a 3rd extra line 
\newpage
reference \R{hello} hello
reference within document works fine \lr{hello}
\end{document}
```

This works as expected, especially when you do multiple compiles to update the aux file. However, when I try to reference this document from another document (as seen in the example below), I get a reference to page 2 line 4. I want it to say page 2 line 1.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{test2}
\newcommand{\lr}[1]{page~\pageref{#1}, line~\lineref{#1}}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}
Hello \lr{hello}
\end{document}
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I'm not sure I understand the problem.  The only time the `hello` label is applied is in `test2.tex` so why would you expect your second file to yield page 1 line 1.  Applying `\label{#1} \linelabel{#1}` duplicates the label, it might be wise to name them differently i.e. `\label{#1} \linelabel{line#1}`.

Comment: The ideas is that the second file. Should find the reference in the 1st file and give the same label. However currently when I run these examples the line number is wrong. There was a typo I have edited the question to fix that. So it gives the reference page 2 line 4 when I would expect page 2 line 1. Hope that helps but if i can clarify more I'll be happy to help

Comment: Ah I see, in the second file it has the correct page number but behaves as if the line numbers were not reset by the new page.  So somehow the fact that the `pagewise` option is given in the main document is not being appreciated by referencing it through `\externaldocument`.

Comment: Yeah that's about it. Any ideas?

Comment: http://tug.org/pipermail/texhax/2007-February/007973.html Looks like this is something the current maintainer was looking at but it doesn't seem to have been implemented according to the changelog on CTAN.  Might be worth contacting the package author to ask.

Comment: Having `\label{hello}` and `\linelabel{hello}` creates conflicting labels in the `aux` file, both with name "hello", so using `\linelabel{linehello}` is better. This said, this is unnecessary because `\pageref{linehello}` will give you the page number of a reference created using `\linelabel`. Secondly, `lineno` gives the error "Package lineno Warning: Linenumber reference failed" when processing your second file. Looking at the `lineno` source it seems that it computes the line numbers as it processes the file, so it is not surprising this causes problems. Not sure how to fix this...

Comment: Ok I got in touch with an author. I have appended his comments below. I can't quite figure it out from this.

Comment: pagewise mode employs a nasty machine to calculate line numbers.  It
relys on tokens in the .aux file to find out what the first line counter
value of each page is, and subtratct that for every reference.  The
external and current document both supply those tokens, I'd expect to
get strange results.

I can imagine a fix by instrumenting lineno.sty with a prefix string
that is used for things written into the .aux file, and have an optional
argument for \linelabel to use a different prefix in an external .aux
file.

Comment: Is there any update on this ?!!?